# Ajax post method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, post

I am currently creating a website and am having trouble using AJAX to post my data. I have a button and when clicked the following code is processed...

```
var name = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;
var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML; 

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "php/post.php",  
    data: { postName: name, postText: text},  
    success: function() {  
        $('#paragraph').html("worked");    
    }  
});
```

This definitely opens the post.php page but it is not passing through the desired data. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are those ID `name` and `text` belongs to? A textbox? If yes, then you should use `.value` or `$('#name').val()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do the variables name and text contain? Rather than doing

```
var name = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;
var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
```

You can do:

```
var name = $("#name").val(); 
var text = $("#text").val();
```

You may need to pass the datatype object too:

```
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "php/post.php",  
data: { postName: name, postText: text}, 
dataType: "json",
success: function() {  
    $('#paragraph').html("worked");    
}  
});
```

Comment: dataType is required for receving not for sending, OPs question is that he is not able to send data

Comment: dataType is required for receving not for sending,

Comment: ok changing the it to .val() seemed to fix it and now the data is being processed correctly. Thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var name = $('#name').text();
var text = $('#text').text(); 

$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "php/post.php",  
  data: { postName: name, postText: text}, 
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function() {  
    $('#paragraph').html("worked");    
  }  
});
```

Comment: `.html()` would be equivalent of `innerHTML` -> `.text()` is going to strip off all his markups.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not preventing the default button click behaviour. Probably you should use the `preventDefault` function on the button click to stop processing the default form posting. Also make sure you have the content present inside your form elements with the Id `name` and `text`

```
$(function(){  

    $("#yourButtonId").click(function(e){
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      var name = $('#name').html();
      var text = $('#text').html();

      if(name!="") 
      {    
         $.ajax({  
           type: "POST",  
           url: "php/post.php",  
           data: { postName: name, postText: text},  
           success: function() {  
              $('#paragraph').html("worked");    
           }   
         });  
       }
       else
       {
         alert("Why should i do ajax when content is empty!");
       }
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = document.getElementById('name').value,
    text = document.getElementById('text').value, 
    postData = JSON.stringify({ postName: name, postText: text});
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "php/post.php",  
    data: postData,
    success: function() {  
        $('#paragraph').html("worked");    
    }  
});
```

You will need to include a reference to `json2.js` for this to work in older browsers. You can download it here : https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js